# flyway/springboot - configure to run on production/test but not on dev

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

How to check through `spring-boot` that if the database schema is already present do not run but run if no matching schema. Can I do the following through spring-boot flyway integration.

1. DEV - already has the database tables matching the sql scripts (e.g `V1_Baseline.sql` has both table creation and reference data) so should not run this but will need to create the internal SCHEMA_VERSION table and make this script as already run so that V2_....sql will run next)
2. TEST - has tables that should not be dropped but the scripts need to be run and internal SCHEMA_VERSION table created.
3. PROD - this is empty. So no issues should be there (same as test i guess).

From `flyway` [site](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing)  I saw this:

`flyway clean`  (cannot run - nothing should be dropped)

`flyway baseline` (i think this is the one I need? check if current db is matching then just make current scripts as baseline and dont run if not run the scripts)

Nothing concrete here on [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) spring io too and on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway) too.

I think answer is here with `baseline` and doing some checks but not sure what works.

Comment: I don’t have my laptop in front of me but the easiest way I can think of achieving this is via spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration,filesystem:/opt/migration - have a dev profile which uses an extra separate location with your internal schema version script in there. Hope that helps.

Comment: @RobScully your approach is most likely to work. thx

Answer (score 0):

Baseline is indeed what you need here as it serves this exact purpose.

Comment: How Can I implement a conditional Baseline - ? check if baseline needs to be executed or Can I Baseline be implemented even in prod and test?